# If statment in Excel - Ms Access DB

Tags: excel, ms-access

Can anyone suggest the syntax for the below IF statement,

```
IIf
  (  Cur_Insert_Cost,
     Cur_Insert_Cost/Cur_Insert_Edges,
     Cur_Regrindable_Cost/(Cur_Regrinds_Possible+1)
   ) AS Cur_Cost_Edge_Regrind
```

the above line is from the Excel report with Ms-Access DB

I didn't understand the condition part....!!!

Cur_Insert_Cost, Cur_Insert_Edges, Cur_Regrindable_Cost ... etc are column names

Comment: I'm assuming CUR_Insert_Cost is a boolean (yes/no) field?

Comment: @johnfx Don't think so, its probably a currency field (check the true part of the IIF)

Comment: yes its a Currency field, datatype is Currency...

Answer (score 4):

IIF is a ternary operator. It is composed of three parts separated by comma

```
iif(expression, truepart, falsepart)
```

In your case it means:

```
if  Cur_Insert_Cost is not zero then 
    return the result of the expression Cur_Insert_Cost/Cur_Insert_Edges
else
    return the result of the expression Cur_Regrindable_Cost/(Cur_Regrinds_Possible+1)
```

the result will be named in the query as Cur_Cost_Edge_Regrind

Comment: also bear in mind that unlike `if..then..else..end`, if you use an `iif` then both `truepart` and `falsepart` will be evaluated (and one discarded)

Comment: Steve am trying to have the above statement in mysql, shall i check the condition as if(Cur_Insert_Cost > 0) or do i need to check for null...? if(Cur_Insert_Cost==null) || if(Cur_Insert_Cost<>null)

Comment: Not sure about MySql but if your column `Cur_Insert_Cost` could be null then you should check for this case `IF(((Cur_Insert_Cost Is Null) OR (Cur_Insert_Cost > 0)), ........)`

Answer (score 0):

The test is if Cur_Insert_Cost
is seen as being empty for false or whatever Access counts as false.

So it may mean
Cur_Insert_Cost = NULL, 0, '', false (I guess I forget some alternatives)

As you can see the first part uses is and IIRC 
Cur_Insert_Cost applied to NULL will give an exceptoin (but that's just from my memory)

Answer (score 0):

The statement says that the value of column `Cur_Cost_Edge_Regrind` is:

- the result of `Cur_Insert_Cost/Cur_Insert_Edges` if `Cur_Insert_Cost` is TRUE (or 1)
- the result of `Cur_Regrindable_Cost/(Cur_Regrinds_Possible+1)` if `Cur_Insert_Cost` is FALSE (or 0)

Hope that helps...